# finding KPIs using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have datasets where I have tried to use the pandas groupby function to group the selected columns in the dataset. I would like to get the count of items in a particular column as part of the same dataframe. I can't seem to find a way. I am new to python and pandas. Thanks for the help.

example:-

country  customer_no    Treatment_Group Open
Atlantis 1352202109      Group A    1
Atlantis 1354540751      Group B    1
Atlantis 1354849289      Group A    1
Oceania  1356553036      Group A    1
Oceania  1356553036      Group A    1
Oceania  1356553036      Group A    1
Oceania  1356883118      Group B    0
Oceania  1356883118      Group B    0

Group Country   Rate (count opened/total unique customer))
A    Atlantis   (2/2)*100
A    Oceania    (1/1)*100   rate of distinct customer number who opened
B    Atlantis   (1/1)*100
B    Oceania    *0/1)*100

Comment: Simply do: dataset['column'].count()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.